# dockerfile - How to support python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

Base image in the below dockerfile is using python 2.7

```
FROM openjdk:10.0.2-jdk


RUN     curl -sSLO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/64/a18a487b4391a05b9c7f938b94a16d80305bf0369c6b0b9509e86165e1d3/setuptools-41.0.1.zip && \
    unzip setuptools-41.0.1.zip -d /tmp && \
    cd /tmp/setuptools-41.0.1 && \
    python setup.py install && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*

RUN curl -sSLO https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/ab/f86b61bef7ab14909bd7ec3cd2178feb0a1c86d451bc9bccd5a1aedcde5f/pip-19.1.1.tar.gz && \
    tar  -xzvf pip-19.1.1.tar.gz -C /tmp && \
    cd /tmp/pip-19.1.1 && \
    python setup.py install && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*

ENV VERSION=0.17.0

RUN curl -sSLO https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases/download/v$VERSION/aws-sam-cli-${VERSION}.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz && \
    tar -C /usr/local/bin -zxvf /aws-sam-cli-${VERSION}.x86_64_linux.bottle.tar.gz
```

---

We would like to upgrade to python3.6

But base image does not support the same. Base image cannot be changed, because there are other dependencies relying on this base image

---

How to upgrade python2.7 to python3.6?
 Without changing base image

Comment: I feel like it would be easier to install Java 10 (or newer) into the Python3 base image

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with centos, what i did was I used conda to create a new python 3 environment and then activated this environment in the Dockerfile,

```
RUN conda create -n env python=3.6
RUN echo "source activate env" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/env/bin:$PATH
```

Ofcourse you have to install conda first, for this to work.

Source: https://medium.com/@chadlagore/conda-environments-with-docker-82cdc9d25754